# How to run chomedriver (version 120) using m proxy?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Can you please tell me what the problem might be? I wrote a code on python to connect to the site via proxy, but every time I try to connect using them, the site writes that the server is not available.

```
`   from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
     
    options = Options()
    proxy_server_url = (f"{this is where you insert a random proxy from the list}")
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_server_url}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
    driver.get('my website')
`
```

I tried doing the same thing using firefox, but all also without success. Could it be related to the latest chrom update (120)?

it's like this:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7284/devtools/browser/f1bed451-053b-4cf3-a138-5cdb54621f0b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PS\Desktop\yes.py", line 46, in <module>
    driver.get('my website## Heading ##')
  File "C:\Users\defaultuser0\Videos\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 449, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\defaultuser0\Videos\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\defaultuser0\Videos\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01376EE3+174339]
        (No symbol) [0x012A0A51]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB6FF6]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB3B92]
        (No symbol) [0x00FAB48A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FAA72E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA9B26]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA9ABF]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA89DC]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA8DD8]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB8EB7]
        (No symbol) [0x0101A9D2]
        (No symbol) [0x0100700C]
        (No symbol) [0x0101A104]
        (No symbol) [0x01006DA6]
        (No symbol) [0x00FE1034]
        (No symbol) [0x00FE1F8D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01414B1C+820540]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x014D53EE+653550]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x014D4E09+652041]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x014C97CC+605388]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x014D5D9B+656027]
        (No symbol) [0x012AFE6C]
        (No symbol) [0x012A83B8]
        (No symbol) [0x012A84DD]
        (No symbol) [0x01295818]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x766EFCC9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77697C6E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77697C3E+238]
```